# Phone Authentication in Firebase gives error in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
Error:(24, 32) error: cannot find symbol class PhoneAuthCredential
```

Gradle

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
```

What other gradle file to include to resolve the error for phone authentication in Firebase?Please help

Comment: add `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'` refer this link [FirebasePhoneAuthentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase phone authentication is being supported since the 11.0.0 version of firebase sdk

so you should use the new version of it and the 11.2.0 the last version of it

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0"
```